# Does NGRX selector return store refernce

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, redux, ngrx

I am writing an angular application. in which I am managing state using redux.
I have a store like below

```
export interface State {
  data {
    items: any[];
  }
}
```

I have a return selector for getting Items like below

```
export const getItems = createSelector(getItemState, fromItem.getItems);
```

fromItem.getItems is like below =>

```
export const getItems = (state: State): any[] => state.items;
```

and in my component I have subscribe for selector of items like below

```
this.store.select(getItems).subscribe((items) => {
      this.localItems = items;
}
```

everything is working fine but in getItems subscription I am getting the reference to the items which are stored in the store. And, if I update any local item it also gets reflected into the store.

I was expecting the subscription of selector (getItems) to return a cloned copy of items from the store but it is returning the reference.

Am I doing anything wrong or is there any way to get a cloned copy of items from the store?

Comment: Indeed it returns reference to the object in store. And objects in store are to be immutable. if you need to change an object in store you always do it via dispatching an action. In you case you have to deep copy those objects you want to edit locally

Comment: Maybe you should have a look to [Ngrx Entity](https://ngrx.io/guide/entity) which is a great help to manage collections.

Answer (score 2):

What you're describing is the correct behavior.
State mutations should only happen in reducers in a *pure* way.

Doing it this way makes using a store performant, we can simply check if the reference is the same - this is very cheap.